# Calculate time spend in countries

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to find a way to detect time spend in countries for cars.

This is my table keeping track of when/how records are stored:

```
car_id, seen,      country

001     2021-02-03 germany
001     2021-02-21 germany
001     2021-03-02 germany
001     2021-03-10 france
001     2021-03-21 germany
003 ...
```

Idea of output could be something in the realm of:

```
car_id, seen,      country, interval_in_same_country

001     2021-02-03 germany  0 days
001     2021-02-21 germany  18 days  
001     2021-03-02 germany  27 days
001     2021-03-10 france   0 days
001     2021-03-21 germany  0 days
003 ...
```

Maybe there is better out, but that's my initial idea.
Any help on how to make such calculations?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: What is the meaning of all these `0 days`? I guess you want '11 days' for the row with country = france.

Comment: No, the first time we see `france` is `2021-03-10`. We don't know if it has been in Germany before or just entered France.

Comment: By what logic is 27 obtained and the rest 0?

Comment: Don't you want in the results the number of days the car was in france? This should be 11 days and not 0.

Comment: But how do you know if the car has been in France for 11 days - if the only/first record we have of it is 2021-03-10. It might have changed to Germany same day or the day after - but the next record we have is in Germany 2021-03-21 - but this doesn't mean the car haven't traveled in between - we simply don't have other records.

Comment: The same applies to any row then. How do you know that the car has been in germany for 18 days? Your requirement is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the window functions `lag()` and `sum()`

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (car_id,seen,country) *, 
    coalesce(CASE 
               WHEN LAG(country) OVER (ORDER BY seen) <> country THEN 0
             ELSE 
               seen-LAG(seen) OVER (PARTITION BY car_id,country ORDER BY seen )
             END,0) AS days
  FROM t 
  ORDER BY seen ASC)
SELECT car_id,seen,country,
  CASE WHEN days <> 0 AND LAG(days) OVER w <> 0 THEN
    sum(days) OVER w
  ELSE days
  END interval_in_same_country
FROM j 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY car_id,country ORDER BY seen ASC)
ORDER BY seen ;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=36145439dfde2c471cef7943dc1e6b68)

Comment: Getting `Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  CASE types interval and integer cannot be matched LINE 4:   0`

Comment: @AlfredBalle Did you check the fiddle? Also, can you modify this fiddle with the data that causes the error and send us the link?

Comment: Seems to work in the fiddle-demo. Only thing is that the fiddle shows germany for respectively 18 and 9 days, and the one with 9 days should be combined into 18+9=27 days - otherwise really nice :)

Comment: @AlfredBalle perhaps this might help: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7d9c1e981b6ee603913074d714e6ceac

Comment: Just tried to add a few more records, spanning another month: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=12497116d4f86c6ab7f622e42972d366. Seems to break the sum across days in same country?

Comment: Also this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eae64a65c80201801fbb2a3a0304e58a. Same issue.

Comment: @AlfredBalle I believe I do not fully understand your use case :-D perhaps it's due the fact that there are repeated rows in your last data sample? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=21c1e8b54690739c7174e5e747176b3a

Comment: It's simply that if there is multiple records on the same date, then it breaks to sum of days spend in a country. Or if records spans multiple months, as in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=12497116d4f86c6ab7f622e42972d366 then you can see Germany counts 18, 27, 40, when it in fact should be 18, 27, 58 (not 40 as the final number).

Comment: Not sure if this confuses, but shows both findings: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8166b2454d0bf99ea126d190ad2ee0ea.

Comment: @AlfredBalle but it still has to restart counting if it is chronologically the first record in a country, right?

Comment: @AlfredBalle next shot.. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=36145439dfde2c471cef7943dc1e6b68

Comment: Seems to work beautiful, amazing. Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe not, seems to break if I'm adding a few more records from same date into it:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1c72b5888213c6e6a1c5d29faeb004ad
compared to yours:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=36145439dfde2c471cef7943dc1e6b68

Comment: @AlfredBalle in that case you might wanna make sure that the dates are distinct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c3539d1920e604f94dad2061c0801dcb does it help?

Answer (score 1):

you can use lag window function

```
select 
  car_id,
  seen,
  country,
  case 
    when interval_in_same_country < 0 then (interval_in_same_country * (-1))
    when interval_in_same_country is null then 0
    else interval_in_same_country
  end as interval_in_same_country
from
  (select * ,
      case 
        when lag(country) over (order by seen) <> country then 0
        else DATE_PART('day', seen::timestamp) - DATE_PART('day', lag(seen,1) over(order by car_id)::timestamp)
        end as interval_in_same_country

   from table) t
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `column "day" does not exist`.

Comment: I put the appropriate PostgreSQL 9.0 code in the answer. Your question is not clear, but in the answer, it compares the records of each row with the previous row and shows them in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` with three arguments and some conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(country) over (order by car_id) = country
             then seen - lag(seen, 1, seen) over (order by car_id)
             else interval '0 day'
        end) 
from t;
```

Comment: Getting error `ERROR:  CASE types integer and interval cannot be matched` - 
`ERROR seen - lag(seen, 1, seen) over (order by car_id)`

Comment: @AlfredBalle . . . I think that is due to the default condition.  Seems strange, though.  What data type is `seen`?  In your question is looks like a date, and the above should work fine.  However, if it is a timestamp, then you need an explicit `interval`, as this db<>fiddle illustrates:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=88c6c6d1edbfd1698565e3a63d76781f.